# C# Add List class to new List class without looping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, object, arraylist

I have a list of users returned in a class

My Class: List

```
public class EmployeeList
{
    public int Emp_No { get; set; }
    public string Sys_Prefix { get; set; }
    public short Company_No { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Known_As { get; set; }
    public string Initials { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

without looping through the results of this class i want to add the results to a new list `var newsFeedEmps = new List<NewsFeedEmployees>();`

```
public partial class NewsFeedEmployees
{
    public long Company_No { get; set; }
    public long Emp_No { get; set; }
    public long SourceId { get; set; }
    public string Sys_Prefix { get; set; }

    public long NewsFeedID { get; set; }

    public bool isActive { get; set; }
}
```

I cant use newsFeedEmps.AddRange(EmployeeList) because not all the parameters match and i will be assigning a separate value to NewsFeedID and isActive for the full list

I don't want to use a foreach loop to loop through the first list and do a newsFeedEmps.Add(new .... )
I found a separate post mentioning

```
Queue<NewsFeedEmployees> myQueue = new Queue<NewsFeedEmployees>();
myQueue.EnqueueRange(emps.Select(emp => new NewsFeedEmployees()
{
    Company_No = emp.Company_No,
    Emp_No = emp.Emp_No,
}));
```

But i get an error that Queue does not contain a definition for EnqueueRange

Comment: Why without looping? Copying one list to another is inherently an `O(n)` operation.

Comment: You could use LINQ: `var newList = oldList.Select(...).ToList();`, but internally that's using loops anyway.

Comment: The code in the question doesn't match what you're actually asking. Can you change it to be more realistic?

Comment: _"Queue does not contain a definition for EnqueueRange"_ - what made you think it would?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by `not all parameters match`. If you use generic collections, all items in the collection *must* have matching types. You could use non-generic collections, but that is not something I would recommend.

Comment: Apologies if my code language is incorrect. 

-@JonasH What i mean by not all parameters match, is the class i need to assign values to from the first class does not have all the same parameters, or objects, or variable names, so a .AddRange wont work, they are different classes
-@Fildor i tried it because a similar query had it as a solution, thus i thought it would, but it didn't, thus is the use of stack overflow, to learn
-@stuartd I dont understand, i feel i've explained my query efficiently and supplied the code in effect
-@JohnathanBarclay trying to reduce time taken, thx for sugg

Comment: The existence of a member (which a method like "AddRange" is) depends on the type, not on a similarity in query. If a query had a result type of List<T>, that would provide some other members than a result of IQueryable<T> or IEnumerable<T> ... though you could have similarly looking queries producing them.

Comment: But back to your question: "No looping" - does that _actually mean_ "no loops, please" or just "please hide those pesky loops behind an api for me"?

Comment: I mean you could create an experience like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CWp9LH which still _uses_ loops. Just that these are "hidden" from you as the consumer of the API that is created by the extensions.

Comment: This question has "XY problem" written all over it. That is, you have some real problem to solve, you have some wrong idea about how to solve it, and now you're asking a very confusing question about the wrong idea. What is the problem you are *actually* trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in various ways without an explicit *for* loop, but if the goal is

> [trying to reduce time taken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78000648/c-sharp-add-list-class-to-new-list-class-without-looping#comment137511809_78000648)

I'm quite confident that you can't do better than *O(n)* (actually *θ(n)*).

Here's a way you can avoid an explicit `for` loop. If you want to go with something already built in, you can write the operation like this:

```
Queue<NewsFeedEmployees> myQueue = new Queue<NewsFeedEmployees>();
emps.Select(emp => new NewsFeedEmployees
    {
        Company_No = emp.Company_No,
        Emp_No = emp.Emp_No,
    })
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(myQueue.Enqueue);
```

Unfortunately, `ForEach` is only available on `List<T>`, which is why `ToList()` is required.

This actually loops through `emps` *twice*, but still has *θ(n)* running time.

You might think, then, that you could write your own `ForEach` extension method directly on `IEnumerable<T>`, and while you can, as Eric Lippert explains, there's [not much point in doing that](https://ericlippert.com/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/).

If, however, we assume that `emps` is already a `List<EmployeeList>` you could also do this:

```
Queue<NewsFeedEmployees> myQueue = new Queue<NewsFeedEmployees>();
emps.ForEach(emp => myQueue.Enqueue(new NewsFeedEmployees
    {
        Company_No = emp.Company_No,
        Emp_No = emp.Emp_No,
    }));
```

This, at least, only implicitly loops through `emps` once. It's still *θ(n)*, although it's theoretically twice as fast as the previous suggestion.

In any case, `List<T>.ForEach` loops through the list once, and I feel confident stating that you can't do better than that.

In a language like F# or Haskell, one could implement the same kind of operation with recursion instead of explicit loops, but it would still be an *θ(n)* operation.

Ultimately, though, unless you have millions of records, don't worry. As [Rob Pike stated](https://users.ece.utexas.edu/%7Eadnan/pike.html),

> n is usually small.

Answer (score 0):

-> In Your Case, Without using foreach loop, you can use method to each item to convert in EmployeeList to NewsFeedEmployees object. and create new List from result.

-> Follow my code to solve your problem.

Code :-

```
List<EmployeeList> employees = /* your list of EmployeeList */;
List<NewsFeedEmployees> newsFeedEmps = employees.Select(emp => new 
 NewsFeedEmployees
 {
    Company_No = emp.Company_No,
    Emp_No = emp.Emp_No,
    // Assign values to other properties as needed
    SourceId = 0, // Example value, replace with actual value
    NewsFeedID = 0, // Example value, replace with actual value
    isActive = true // Example value, replace with actual value
  }).ToList();
```